# Difference between golang new() vs struct literal, especially in memory allocation

Tags: go

Say I have a struct:

```
type foo struct {
}
```

Are there any difference between

```
f := &foo{}
```

and

```
f := new(foo)
```

in terms of the machine code it gets compiled into, or it's just merely a syntax difference?

A more specific question:

As for struct literal (`&foo{}`), the memory can be allocated in stack or heap, depends on the escape analysis.

However for `new(foo)`, I am not quite sure:

`calloc()` in c is similar to `new()` in golang from my understanding. But `calloc()` always allocate on heap. I am wondering if `new()` always allocate in heap?

The golang spec (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation) only mentioned:

> The built-in function new takes a type T, allocates storage for a
>   variable of that type at run time, and returns a value of type *T
>   pointing to it. The variable is initialized as described in the
>   section on initial values.

It does not say where `new()` will allocate the memory. So does `new()` always allocate on heap, or it can also be allocated in stack as well --- Exactly same as struct literal in memory allocation?